# How to select entries from one table where a certain field is not existing in the other table

Tags: sqlite, peewee

How to select entries in peewee ORM from one table where a certain field is not in the other table?

E.g.
How to count the employees which is there in tblemployees and not in tblcards?

```
select count(*) from tblEmployees 
   where name not in 
   (select employname from tblCards);
```

Note: Both fields, "name" and "employname" are not the respective primary/foreign keys).

Comment: Please provide a MRE as described for the tag you used. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info

Comment: Please explain how the query you show fails and show the difference of the result you get to the result you want for the sample data you provide in your MRE.

Comment: You need to provide your model definitions. But did you try thing something like `Employee.select().where(Employee.name.not_in(Card.select(Card.employname))).count()`

Comment: Thank you @booshong, that is the solution! Was not aware of that.
(If you post this as reply, I will put it to solved.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide your model definitions. But did you try something like:

```py
Employee.select().where(Employee.name.not_in(Card.select(Card.employname))).count()
```